# What do these F scores mean ? Using SelectKBest feature

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am new to Statistics.I am trying to select the best features to do classification on my data set and I chose to do so by running SelectKbest from scikitlearn.

Here is my code :

```
 import sklearn.feature_selection as fs
 kb = fs.SelectKBest(k=10)
 kb.fit(X, y)
 names = X.columns.values[kb.get_support()]
 scores = kb.scores_[kb.get_support()]
 names_scores = list(zip(names, scores))
 ns_df = pd.DataFrame(data = names_scores, columns=
  ['Feat_names','F_Scores'])
 ns_df_sorted = ns_df.sort_values(['F_Scores','Feat_names'], ascending =
  [False, True])
 print(ns_df_sorted)
```

This gives an output like this

```
  Feat_names   F_Scores
4     go_out  29.870218
8     fun1_2  27.374212
6     fun1_1  26.470766
3       date  25.035227
7    shar1_1  17.629153
2    imprace  11.331197
0      order  11.290014
5    sinc1_1   8.309805
9    shar1_2   5.009775
1   field_cd   4.515538
```

I am not sure what the F score here signifies and what I can interpret from it.

Comment: These are ANOVA f-scores. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12398/how-to-interpret-f-and-p-value-in-anova) and [here](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/understanding-analysis-of-variance-anova-and-the-f-test).

Answer (score 1):

You can understand the F-Scores as a measure of how informative each feature is for your dataset.

As it is explained in [the method documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection), an F-test is carried out to assess each feature. The F-scores are the test statistic for the [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test), and they basically represent the **ratio between the explained and the unexplained variance**.

So, in your example, after using the feature selection method you could either take all the `k=10` most informative features or you could use the scores to refine more your selection (e.g. choosing only those for which the F-score is higher than some threshold).